# Rename one level of a factor in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm attempting to rename the level `A` of factor `column1` in the dataframe `df` in R. My current approach is this:

```
levels(df[!is.na(df$column1) & df$column1 == 'A',]) <- 'B'
```

which doesn't throw any errors or warnings but is completely ineffective.

`B` is not an already existing level (which from trial and error I came to suspect was important), so the following, my first attempt, didn't work either

```
df[!is.na(df$column1) & df$column1 == 'A', 'column1'] <- 'B'
```

Could anyone guide me to the correct approach?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was going to suggest

```
levels(df$column1)[levels(df$column1)=="A"] <- "B"
```

or use the utility function `plyr::revalue`:

```
library("plyr")
df <- transform(df,
          column1=revalue(column1,c("A"="B")))
```

`transform()` is a little sugar that's not necessary; you could use `df$column1 <- revalue(df$column1(...))`

For completeness, `car::recode` also works, although I find it a little bit clunkier than `plyr::revalue` (because the recoding is specified as a quoted string).

```
car::recode(df$column1,"'A'='B'")
```

More recently `forcats::fct_recode()` can also be used for this.

Comment: That's the best I could come up with too. This is one of those instances where R's indexing is really not very neat.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be just to change the label of the level. First, some test data

```
df <- data.frame(column1=c("A","B","C","A","B"))
```

and now we replace "A" with "X"

```
levels(df$column1) <- gsub("A","X", levels(df$column1))
```

and we can see that it's changed

```
  column1
1       X
2       B
3       C
4       X
5       B
```

You might need to be careful with `gsub()` since it accepts a regular expression. A more specific replacement would be

```
gsub("^A$","X", levels(df$column1))
```

to match exactly "A" and not "CAB" or something else with a capital A.

Comment: `gsub` is a bit risky here. What if you had the levels "A" and "Ajax"?

Comment: @thelatemail i was making that edit as you commented.